# Remove All $_GET Variables from URL - htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, permalinks, getparameter

I'm having an issue in trying to get my search URL to be "SEO Friendly", at the moment my URL currently looks like this -
www.example.com/pagename?param1=SELECTED-FEATURE&location=ENTERED-LOCATION

If the user wants to search for multiple features
the URL looks like www.example.com/pagename?param1=SELECTED-FEATURE&param1=SELECTED-FEATURE&location=ENTERED-LOCATION .

If the user selects one feature I would like my URL to be written like the following - www.example.com/pagename/SELECTED-FEATURE/ENTERED-LOCATION

If the user selects multiple features I would like the URL to be written like the following - 
www.example.com/pagename/SELECTED-FEATURE/SELECTED-FEATURE/ENTERED-LOCATION

I do not want to use the POST method.

Thanks,
Codarz360

Answer (score 1):

You could put some values that the user don't need to see in a PHP Sesion or instead of sending them with GET you should use POST?

Comment: I don't want to use the POST method due to the fact that when you click back you are asked resubmit the form.

Comment: Then you could first save the users data in a Sesion variable and then relode to the same page or something...

Comment: For redirecting you can use something like this: 
$current_url = explode("?", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
header('Location: '.$current_url[0]);
But it must be declarated befor HTML code..